# How does Maven automatically inherit properties from parent pom.xml in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am not sure whether I have understood inheritance in Maven `pom.xml` correctly or not. From my understanding I have to define common properties in Parent `pom.xml`, then in Child project those properties can be inherited.

My confusion started when I created a new Maven project using Spring Tool Suite IDE. I created a project through File → New → Spring Started Project. I got the base folder structure created for Maven with default `pom.xml`. When I analysed the default `pom.xml`, it has the following parent tag:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I have not defined any parent `pom.xml`. I am wondering from which parent pom the above attributes are reference?

Note: I am using STS embedded Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the maven artifact `spring-boot-starter-parent` from the group `org.springframework.boot` in version `1.5.7.RELEASE` is set to be your parent. The same way a dependency would be searched for, the parent is searched for... so you probably don't have this parent in your local maven repository, so maven central is called (the same way maven central would be called to find slf4j, hibernate or any other referenced dependency).